# Video Uploading Android

Tags: android

when i try to upload a video of size greater than 20MB the server not getting any parameters that am sending. Am sending video and also jsonobject as string to server.Am using httpmime-4.1.1 jar.Below is my code. Am new to android development any help will be appreciable.I need the solution fast. Please help me

```
String s = json;
Log.d("message", "s==="+s);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
StringBuilder sq = null;                                                                    // Limit

String result = null;
String result1 = null;
try {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);



    Log.d("message","video"+ bin.getFilename());

    reqEntity.addPart("video",bin);



    reqEntity.addPart("arguments", new StringBody(s.toString()));           

    post.setEntity(reqEntity);
    int timeoutConnection = 60000;
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
            timeoutConnection);
    int timeoutSocket = 60000;

    HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        Log.v("@WebSErvice:"+response, "Result0" + response);
        if (response == null) {
            result = null;
        } else {

            try {
                TieWebServicesComponents BWSC = new TieWebServicesComponents(
                        TieWebServicesComponents.POST_TASK, mContext);
                result = BWSC.inputStreamToString(response.getEntity()
                        .getContent());
                Log.v("message:CommunityHome Response"+response, "Result1" + result);

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }

        }

    }catch(NullPointerException ne){


    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}

//Log.v("@WebSErvice:", "REsult" + result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Video Uploading not working in YII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197101/video-uploading-not-working-in-yii)
this link helped me.. There was no error in code.It was the problem in server side.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before , i have track which can be up to 80mb and uploading using `MultiPartEntity` try below function.

```
public class asyncUploadtrack extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
    {
        HttpResponse response;
        private android.app.ProgressDialog dialog;
        long totalSize;

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {

        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
        {

        }
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            Log.i("Do in Backgtound", "Background");
            String url =app.WEB_API_URL+"?op="+ Constant.METHOD_UPLOAD_TRACK;
            File video = new File(trackPath); // path of file 
            Bitmap out = Constant.bitmapResize(TrackFragment.btmTrackImg,308, 296) ;//Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(TrackFragment.btmTrackImg, 408, 396,true);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            out.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);




             try 
            {
                MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                multipartEntity.addPart("music", new FileBody(video));
                multipartEntity.addPart("title",new StringBody(trackTitle));
                multipartEntity.addPart("user", new StringBody(app.preferences.getStringPref("userId")));


                multipartEntity.addPart("filename", new StringBody("song.mp3"));
                multipartEntity.addPart("avatar",new ByteArrayBody(data, "trackImage"));
                //After adding everything we get the content's lenght
                totalSize = multipartEntity.getContentLength();
                post.setEntity(multipartEntity);
                response = httpclient.execute(post);
                try 
                {
                    Log.i("Response is",response.getStatusLine().toString());
                                    } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code bt the server not getting any values

Answer (score 0):

Check this code it will help you.

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null; 
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss();

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
               }
           });

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try {

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                  +" F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });               
               }   

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss(); 
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss(); 
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e); 
          }
          dialog.dismiss();      
          return serverResponseCode;

       } // End else block
     }
```

Also check this link. 
http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/file-upload-on-php-server-in-android.html

Good luck.

Comment: Could you explain what in the code you have posted is an answer to the problem happening here, so that the user and future readers can learn from it? Additionally, this isn't an answer so much as just copying the code at the link. While you must include credit when you use someone else's content, you also must include some of your own content.