# Video Uploading not working in YII

Tags: android, video, yii

I have a strange isuue in Yii.

We are using Yii for webservice with Android and IOS. In the mobile there have video uploading page.

This is the code iam using in Yii to upload video:

```
$file_path_image = "";
                $directory='images/Post';
                $file_path_video = "";
                $model = new TblCommunity();
                if(isset($_FILES['video'])){
                    $file = $_FILES['video'];
                    print_r($file);
                    $videoID = $model->getRandomString();
                    $video_obj = new VideoUpload();
                    $result = array();
                    $video_result_temp = $video_obj->upload($file, $videoID, $directory);
                    $result = CJSON::decode($video_result_temp);
                    if(isset($result['status']) && $result['status'] == 'failed'){                          
                        $result['response'] = array();
                        $result['status']='failed';
                        $this->_sendResponse(201, CJSON::encode($result));
                    } else {                                            
                        $file_path_video = Yii::app()->params['BASE_URL'].$result['Path'];                      
                    }
                }
```

The above code will work for small size videos.

But when the mobile guys start to upload a big size or above 5MB , I didnt get any data in Yii.

Its wasting my a week full of time.

What is the reason for this strange behaviour?

All helps are appreciable.

When sending large size video , the Yii returns error as `Undefined index 'video'`.

Comment: there is no code with index 'video', may be you should write it too.

Comment: that was a mistake.....

Comment: but it again shows the same above error

Comment: where is this mistake?

Comment: i just misspelled name of the file object. the real name is `video' but i misspeleld it as 'video_thumb'

Comment: that means problem in server or php settings, did you check them?

Comment: i just printed the phpinfo details it have `upload_max_filesize 20M 20M`, iam trying to upload below 15MB video, but it fails and return the above error

Comment: Check post_max_size in PHP

Comment: oh that is `post_max_size 8M 8M`....

Comment: Is this need to increase?

Comment: yes, set 2x more than upload_max_filesize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be 2 reasons:

1. Model rules (max file size)
2. Php/Server settings (upload_max_filesize, post_max_size)

Did you check this already?

Comment: i never set any size limit in models

Comment: When sending large size video , the Yii returns error as `Undefined index 'video'`.